# assembly fatal error LNK1190: invalid fixup found, type 0x0001

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, masm

I want to write 16 bit 8086 assembly code in visual studio 2010
but gives me error:
code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
message BYTE "Hello, world!","$"
.code
mov ah,9
mov dx,OFFSET message ; addr of buffer
int 21h
END
```

output gives me this error:

```
fm.obj : fatal error LNK1190: invalid fixup found, type 0x0001
```

I using **masm32v11**. What should I do?

Comment: I think you'll need an older copy of the linker for this.

Comment: I tried [link](http://www.scs.carleton.ca/~sivarama/asm_book_web/free_MASM.html) but when I built asm masm crash!

Comment: Are you sure MASM32 can compile 16 bit applications? At least you must have some directive to switch it to 16bit mode. The assembler can't know what you are trying to do. IMO, you must try FASM - it can create 16bit applications. (also 32bit and 64bit)

Comment: The last version of Visual Studio that had a linker that could link this 16-bit code was version 1.52.  Published *20 years* ago.  Talk to your teacher and ask him how to get the tooling you need, most of it is part of a museum exhibit and hard to obtain and install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where does the Assembler know where the starting address is?
Using `Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994` (16bit linker)
and added `start` and `end start` the code Assembles and links just fine.  MASM32 includes a 16bit linker in the bin directory.  You **must** pass different command line parameters to ML to Assemble 16bit code correctly though.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
message BYTE "Hello, world!","$"
.code
start:
mov ah,9
mov dx,OFFSET message ; addr of buffer
int 21h
END start
```

So to recap - your code needs a starting address and an end,
You can use the current ML that comes with MASM32 to Assemble 16 bit and 32 bit code.  To link 16 bit code you must use a 16 bit linker, to link 32 bit code, you must use a 32 bit linker.

From one of my 16 bit DOS apps:

```
ML.EXE /DMASM /DDOS /Zm /c /nologo /I"f:\masm32\Include" "dosdisplay.asm"
link16.exe /NOLOGO "dosdisplay.obj"
```

Comment: I found 16 bit linker and put it in bin folder but no change in vs occurred

Answer (score 2):

Assemble and link with these commands:

> ml.exe /omf  filename.asm
>
> link16.exe filename.obj

**Info:**

When you invoke `ml.exe` without any specific parameters the type of object file that it generates will be in COFF format. COFF format name mangling requires that your code should have a `_start` and `end _start`. what you have written will work for Intel's OMF object files.

Comment: Could you state a bit about those commands so that others could understand what you are running there, please?