# LNK1190: invalid fixup found, type 0x0001

Tags: assembly, tasm

Having trouble with "LNK1190: invalid fixup found, type 0x0001"
Can't understand, where did I make a mistake. 
I am using TASM Visual Studio. Didn't find any answers before. Can someone tell, where is the problem?
This code suppose to get lines and change places of first and last symbol in them.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.486

.code


jmp start

.data
mess   db   'String: $'
buff   db   12 dup(0),'$'
len    equ  12


.code
start: 
       mov   ah,9              
       lea dx, mess
       int   21h
       mov   cx,len
       lea di,buff           
       push  cx

       mov   ah,1             
input: int   21h
       stosb                 
       loop  input

       pop   si
begin: lodsb                 
       push  ax              
       loop  begin

       lea di,buff           
       mov   cx,len
write: pop   ax            
       stosb                 
       loop  write

       mov   ah,2         
       xor   bx,bx
       mov   dh,10
       mov   dl,30
       int   10h

       mov   ah,9         
       lea dx,buff           
       int   21h

       xor   ax,ax
       int   16h
       int 20h

       int 21h
       END start
```

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692582/assembly-fatal-error-lnk1190-invalid-fixup-found-type-0x0001

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assembly fatal error LNK1190: invalid fixup found, type 0x0001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692582/assembly-fatal-error-lnk1190-invalid-fixup-found-type-0x0001)